# Plesk fails on installation mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, plesk, plesk-onyx

Trying to install plesk on an ec2 (currently 3 sites running) I have. From what i've read plesk will only work on a vanilla server (hoping this is not the case).

Installation crashes on the line:

```
Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd- 
sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
```

After this the error is:

```
 Trying to establish test connection... mysql: [Warning] World-writable config                
 file '/root/.my.cnf' is ignored.
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: 
 NO) failed
 One more attempt to connect

 ERROR while trying to establish test connection. If you are installing Plesk 
on an already configured MySQL server, you need to specify the administrator's 
credentials to succeed with the installation. To do this, you need to create a 
file - /root/.my.cnf with the 'client' section where you need to provide user 
and its password ("user = $admin_name" and "password = $admin_pass"). After 
installation is finished, the file /root/.my.cnf will be renamed to 
/root/.my.cnf.bak
Check the error reason(see log file: 
/var/log/plesk/install/plesk_17.8.11_installation.log), fix and try again

 *****  problem report *****
ERROR while trying to establish test connection. If you are installing Plesk on 
an already configured MySQL server, you need to specify the administrator's 
credentials to succeed with the installation. To do this, you need to create a 
file - /root/.my.cnf with the 'client' section where you need to provide user 
and its password ("user = $admin_name" and "password = $admin_pass"). After 
installation is finished, the file /root/.my.cnf will be renamed to 
/root/.my.cnf.bak
Check the error reason(see log file: 
/var/log/plesk/install/plesk_17.8.11_installation.log), fix and try again
sh: 1: /etc/init.d/psa: not found
```

I have added the file /root/.my.cnf like so:

```
Client
User: xyz
Password: xyzxyz
```

But it still can't pick it up or use it (changed permissions over and over).

Has anyone been able to get past this error?

Cheers

Comment: /root/.my.cnf should be like:

[client]
user = root
password = root_password

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to install Plesk on the server where mysql is already installed.
It's needed to create a file /root/.my.cnf with root access to mysql:

```
# cat /root/.my.cnf
[client]
user = root
password = root_password
```

But it's not recommended to install Plesk on the server where sites are already running because apache and nginx configuration files can be changed.